# How to handle "unseen" categorical variables with one hot encoding in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a training data (df_train) in which I applied 3rd polynomial to variable x1 and also one hot encoding approach to color variables. The goal is to get the coefficient for each independent variable and predict the Y (target variable) in the testing data (df_test).

As you can see from the below code, training data only has 3 colors (green, red and purple) where testing data has 2 additional colors which are yellow and black. In such case, yellow and black are unseen categorical variables in the testing data.

I have done some researches and found good amount of tutorials/posts on handling unseen categorical variables but I couldn't find any specific examples similar to my case with sklearn Pipeline, ColumnTransformer and PolynomialFeatures.

Any suggestion and advice specific to my use case are greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Training data
x1 = [28.0, 29.0, 12.0, 12.0, 42.0]
x2 = [0.36, 0.53, 0.45, 0.48, 0.4] 
y = [59.5833333333333, 59.5833333333333, 10.0, 10.0, 47.0833333333333] 
color = ['green','red','red','purple','purple']

df_train = pd.DataFrame({
'x1': x1,
'x2' :x2,
'y': y,
'color':color})

df_train['color'].unique()
# array(['green', 'red', 'purple'], dtype=object)

# testing data - yellow and black are unseen categorical featurs
x1_test = [35.0, 28.0, 30.0, 32.0, 46.0] 
x2_test = [0.44, 0.44, 0.6, 0.39, 0.39]
color_test =  ['green','red','purple','yellow','black']

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
'x1': x1_test,
'x2' :x2_test,
'color':color_test})

df_test['color'].unique()
# array(['green', 'red', 'purple', 'yellow', 'black'], dtype=object)


X = df_train[['x1', 'x2', 'color']]
y = df_train['y']

# I need to apply 3rd polynomial to x1 variable only. variable color is converted to dummy 
# variable
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[
('encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), ['color']),
('transformer', PolynomialFeatures(degree=3, include_bias=False), ['x1']),
],
remainder='passthrough')

pipeline = Pipeline([
('preprocessor', preprocessor),
('regressor', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True))])

pipeline.fit(X, y)

print(pipeline['regressor'].intercept_)
# -12.235254842701742

print(pipeline['regressor'].coef_)
# [ 1.12300403 -0.55836609 -0.56463793  0.12934888  0.19512496 -0.00390984
#  -0.20906133]

list_coeff = pipeline['regressor'].coef_ # get the coefficient
list_col = preprocessor.get_feature_names() # get name for each coefficient
dic = {list_col[i]: list_coeff[i] for i in range(len(list_col))} # create a dic for each 
# coefficient and its corresponding name
print(dic)

# {'encoder__x0_green': 1.123004029501841, 'encoder__x0_purple': -0.5583660948050801, 
#'encoder__x0_red': -0.5646379346959568, 
# 'transformer__x0': 0.12934888105186387, 'transformer__x0^2': 0.19512495572810412, 
#'transformer__x0^3': -0.003909843646823246, 
# 'x2': -0.20906132968981733}

# Also apply one hot encoder to testing data, so I can plug in the equation to predict Y in 
# testing data
columns_to_category = ['color']
df_test[columns_to_category] = df_test[columns_to_category].astype('category') 
df_test = pd.get_dummies(df_test, columns=columns_to_category) # One hot encoding the categories

df_test.columns
# Index(['x1', 'x2', 'color_black', 'color_green', 'color_purple', 'color_red',
#        'color_yellow'],
#       dtype='object')

# These are coefficient 
intercept = -12.235254842701742
poly3 = -0.00390984364682324
poly2 = 0.19512495572810412
poly1 = 0.12934888105186387
x2 = -0.20906132968981733
col_green = 1.123004029501841
col_purple = -0.5583660948050801
col_red = -0.5646379346959568

# Predict Y value from testing data. Problem is coefficient for color black and color yellow 
# are missing. Any solution to offer?
df_test['yhat'] = intercept + df_test['x1']**3*poly3 \
             + df_test['x1']**2*poly2  + df_test['x1']*poly1 \
             + df_test['x2'] * x2 \
             + df_test['color_black'] * col_blk \
             + df_test['color_green'] * col_green \
             + df_test['color_purple'] * col_purple \
             + df_test['color_red'] * col_red \
             + df_test['color_yellow'] * col_yellow
```

Comment: It is not clear what specific advice you are looking for because your question is quite vague, and [bpfrd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73047337) is a very appropriate response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're first fitting your encoder on the training set, save the categories OneHotEncoder produces.

```
oh = OneHotEncoder()
encoded = oh.fit_transform(categorical_attribute)
attribute_cats = oh.categories_
```

Then you can use those categories when transforming the test samples.

```
oh = OneHotEncoder(categories=attribute_cats)
test_encoded = oh.fit_transform(test.iloc[:3])
```

Categories, unseen in the testset, will have zeros in `oh.categories_[0][i]` columns.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful and informative

Answer (score 1):

`OneHotEncoder` has parameters such as `max_categories` and `handle_unknown`. By setting `handle_unknown='ignore'` When an unknown category is encountered during transform, the resulting one-hot encoded columns for this feature will be all zeros. You can see more information in docs [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html]

Comment: Thanks but how exactly do I implement this and achieve my goal? I can add the handle_unknow = 'ignore' in the OneHotEncoder for the training data but it does not add the unseen variable to this dataset. I need to get the coefficient for each unseen categorical variables from the training data and use them as part of the equation to calculate y predicted from the testing data.